# cut out text from middle of string with supposing width of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

in Dart i interested to know how can i cut text from middle of String? as we know, we can use `TextOverflow.ellipsis` for strings to cut end of strings, but what i want to have?

i want to cut text from middle of string, for example my string is:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,`

how can i cut out from middle with supposing width of widgets to have:

`Lorem i...ng elit,`

or

`Lorem ipsum d...ur adipiscing elit,`

i can't found out any sample code or documentation about this implementation

Comment: I don't understand this part: "with supposing with of widgets to have" what do you mean?

Comment: @LoVe i'm so sorry i updated post `width of widgets`

Comment: Please clarify more the question is still vague, you just want to take half of a string that is inside say for example a TextField right?

Comment: @LoVe no, i want to put this text to `Text()` widget, for example my `Text` widget may be has more width such as `50.0`, `200.0`, if width of the widget has fix size or that have full width, my string should get it right inside, if String length is bigger that the widget width

Comment: English not helping sorry never mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple a bit hacky solution, not the best, but could help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      child: TextWithCut(
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,'),
    );
  }
}

class TextWithCut extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWithCut(this.text, {Key key, this.style}) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var style = this.style ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1;

    // not the perfect solution to find the symbol width:
    // a bold font is wider and some symbols are wider than normal
    var symbolWidth = style.fontSize * 0.6;

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        var numberOfElements = (constraints.maxWidth / symbolWidth).floor();

        return Text(middleCut(text, numberOfElements), style: style);
      },
    );
  }

  String middleCut(String text, int length) {
    const numberOfDots = 3;
    var dotsString = List<String>.filled(numberOfDots, '.').join();

    var leftSizeLengh = ((length - numberOfDots) / 2).floor();
    var rightSizeLength = text.length - leftSizeLengh;
    var leftPart = text.substring(0, leftSizeLengh);
    var rightPart = text.substring(rightSizeLength);
    return '$leftPart$dotsString$rightPart';
  }
}
```